# .Net Core 3.1 Api Certificate Based Authentication throwing Error "ssl connection could not be established. Authentication failed"

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, x509certificate, asp.net-core-3.1

I was trying to make a HttpWebRequest using DotNet Core 3.1 Framework. Client requirement is this should be implemented via certificate based authentication. We had a valid certificate with all details (sslcert, pfx key and password). When I am trying to make api call to client endpoint receiving error "**The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception**". I did tried to resolve this with all possible options and no luck.

Code Snippet

```
var authorization = $"Basic {Base64Encode($"{AppConstants._clientId}:{AppConstants._secretId}")}";
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificates.Import(certName, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(CitiConstants._endpointURL));
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authorization);
            req.ClientCertificates = certificates;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string postData = "login-form-type=cert";
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            postStream.Flush();
            postStream.Close();
            WebResponse resp =await req.GetResponseAsync();

            Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            stream.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you using HttpWebRequest which was deprecated for 10 years ago? Newer developments should use HttpClient.

Comment: ofcourse, even I tried with httpclient. Result remains same